What does "なのかだからこそ、なのか" here mean?

問いかけながら自己紹介になってしまっている。多分花江江はそのことに気が付いているだろう、日向が今、自己嫌悪をしていることを


けれど、なのかだからこそ、なのか花江はそれをじっと受け止め、頷いて話し始めた

I don't understand what "けれど、なのかだからこそ、なのか" here means.
He says that if he talks about this 花江 will notice it. His own self hate. Then he comments accepts that and bows his head and starts talking to him.
I can't really make sense of けれど、なのかだからこそ、なのか? Is this some way of saying? The narration seem to be speculating about something

Isn't it なのだからこそ rather than なのかだからこそ?

なのだからこそなのか means "possibly for this very reason" or "maybe precisely because of that".

(なの)だからこそ means "precisely because of that", and this refers to 気が付いている.
なのか means "possibly" or "presumably". See my answer here.

